# Getting undefined for useContext() hook when functional Context is used

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

BookContext.js

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react'
export const BookContext = createContext()
export default function BookContextProvider(props) {
    const [books, setbooks] = useState([
        { title: 'the way of kings' , id:1 },
        { title: 'the name of the wind', id:2 },
        { title: 'the final empire', id:3 }
    ])
    return (
        <BookContext.Provider value={{books}}>
            { props.children }
        </BookContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Booklist.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { ThemeContext } from '../contexts/ThemeContext'
import { BookContext } from '../contexts/BookContext'
export default function Booklist() {
  // Object destructuring
  const { isLightTheme, light, dark } = useContext(ThemeContext)
  const theme = isLightTheme ? light : dark
  const { books } = useContext(BookContext)
  return (
    <div className="book-list"  style={{color: theme.syntax, background: theme.bg}}>
      <ul>
        <li style={{background: theme.ui}}>the way of kings</li>
        <li style={{background: theme.ui}}>the name of the wind</li>
        <li style={{background: theme.ui}}>the final empire</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  )    
}
```

Getting undefined for useContext().
When destructered the context it throws typeerror.
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'books' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined.
How can I solve this?

Comment: The BookList component is a scoped in `BookContextProvider`?

Comment: oops, I missed this step. Apologies for the silly question.

Comment: You can accept the answer though because it solves the initial problem. With the initial value you won't have the `undefined` value even outside of the Provider tree. It's usually recommended to use it to avoid to deal with falsy values.

Answer (score 1):

By default the context has an undefined value. You can provide an [initial value](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext) to avoid this issue when the component is mounted outside the provider. The `useContext` hook will use the default context value when no provider is found.

```
export const BookContext = createContext({ books: [] });
```